# Python2 increment string in an alphanumeric format

Tags: string, python-2.7, alphanumeric

I'm looking for a snippet which does stuff like :

```
from 'abcd8' string
i want to increment it like 'abcd9' then 'abcda' ... >'abcdz' and next     'abce0', 'abce1' ... 'abcez', 'abcf0' ....
```

Can't find a way to do it :(

I already tried stuff like using 'aaaa'.encode('hex') then increment it, but not working :(

Thanks for help,

Cheers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way of doing it:

```
# written by 'imerso' to a StackOverflow answer
def increment(os):
    s = list(os)
    p = len(os)-1

    while (p >= 0):
        s[p] = chr(ord(s[p]) + 1)

        if s[p] > 'z':
            s[p] = '0'
            p -= 1
            continue

        if s[p] > '9' and s[p] < 'a':
            s[p] = 'a'

        return ''.join(s)


s = raw_input("String: " )

for x in range(1, 32):
    s = increment(s)
    print s
```

Comment: Thanks !! Works fine :)